# my if statement on my discord bot seems to jump right to else even when given a number that is in my list

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

im trying to make a bot that responds with a random peace of text when someone types >test but i dont get any syntax errors but my number gen just goes to else in the if statement instantly :/

source code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from secrets import randbelow
prefix = ">"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = prefix)
 
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("i have connected to discord! ^-^")

@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def test(ctx):
    x = (randbelow(3))
    if x =="1":
        await ctx.send("Yay 1")
    elif x =="2":
        await ctx.send("Yay 2")
    else:
        print("fuck")

bot.run("my token")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`randbelow()` returns an integer, so do

`if x == 1` and so on...

Comment: i feel so unbelievably dumb i put the numbers in brackets ;-;